# Enabling RBS on more than content database (Different site collection)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql, rbs, 2012

I am trying to enable RBS on different content database but first the RBS that I installed was installed by wizards, not using cmd as mentioned in the [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631(v=office.15).aspx) article about installing and configuring RBS.

When I ran it from the cmd the log file contain error about the master key

> raiserror(N'Remote Blob Storage requires a master key to exist in this database. Please create a master key and retry the install.

So I thought it was a permission error for the user who ran the cmd and I added it to the DBOwner but the same problem appear.

The main issue is that I am not able to configure the RBS or enable it in other word for another content database.

Answer (score 2):

RBS isn't configured correctly. You need to have master key in your SharePoint Content database. Use the following command to add it:

```
use [ContentDbName]
if not exists (select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name = N'##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')
create master key encryption by password = N'Admin Key Password !2#4'
```

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748641%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you Jussi for your reply but i checked my content database for that by querying "select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name = N'##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##'" and there was a result

Answer (score 0):

As I predict it was a permission issue.
The user who provision the BLOB store was not a member of the db_owner.
 Thank you for help guys :)